# How do I remove the right side bar on Sublime Text?

Tags: macos, software, sublimetext

When I work in documents with long lines, it gets very annoying because I have to very precisely drag my mouse in order not to accidentally touch that sidebar which drags me back to the beginning. (I'm talking about scrolling/marking horizontally).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are talking about the document preview it is called the *Minimap*. It can be hidden from: **View > Hide Minimap**

Comment: Is there a way to that permanently?

Comment: You have to put a line in your user settings file. [See this answer over on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877319/sublime-text-2-hide-minimap-by-default)